# How to create multiple folders in powershell

Tags: powershell, batch-file

In cmd can be used command `mkdir /data/rs1 /data/rs2 /data/rs3` like:
[image: cmd example]

Everything is correct:

[image: folders example]

But how to realize it in powershell?

I'm trying to use quotes, for example:
[image: powershell]

With quotes I'm getting just one folder and having the issue in powershell:
 [image: folders example]

```
mkdir : Could not find part of the path "rs3".
строка:1 знак:1
+ mkdir "/data/rs1 /data/rs2 /data/rs3"
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (C:\data\rs1 \data\rs2 \data\rs3:String) [New-Item], DirectoryNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CreateDirectoryIOError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewItemCommand
```

Without qoutes also the issue and haven't any folders [image: folders example]: [image: powershell]

```
mkdir : Can not find a positional parameter that takes an argument"/data/rs2".
строка:1 знак:1
+ mkdir /data/rs1 /data/rs2 /data/rs3
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [mkdir], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,mkdir
```

To avoid the issues, I can write without spaces:

```
PS C:\data> mkdir /data/rs1/data/rs2/data/rs3
```

But it will be one folder `rs1` that contains inside `rs2` and `rs3`:

```
C:\data\rs1\data\rs2\data\rs3
```

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`mkdir` can create multiple directories in one go, so no need for `foreach`. you just have to spearate them by commas:

Here I created 3 folders (Hello, Hello2, Hello3) in a directory

```
PS C:\install> mkdir Hello,Hello2,Hello3


    Verzeichnis: C:\install


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
d-----       09.07.2018     10:39                Hello
d-----       09.07.2018     10:39                Hello2
d-----       09.07.2018     10:39                Hello3
```

Here I created 3 folders on separate subfolders in a directory:

```
PS C:\install> mkdir .\xy3\Hello, .\yz3\Hello2, .\tr3\Hello3


    Verzeichnis: C:\install\xy3


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
d-----       09.07.2018     10:42                Hello


    Verzeichnis: C:\install\yz3


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
d-----       09.07.2018     10:42                Hello2


    Verzeichnis: C:\install\tr3


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
d-----       09.07.2018     10:42                Hello3
```

Comment: should be the accepted answer, no ?

Comment: yes, because [`mkdir` is a function that calls `New-Item`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50832054/995714) and [`New-Item`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/new-item?view=powershell-7.2&viewFallbackFrom=powershell-6) receives an array of input paths to create

Answer (score 12):

There are a lot of ways doing this in powershell

```
1..3 | ForEach {MD ".\data\rs$_"}
```

or

```
'RS1','RS2','RS3' | % {New-Item -Name ".\data\$_" -ItemType 'Directory'}
```

or

```
for ($i=1;$i -le 3;$i++){MD ".\data\rs$i"}
```

or

```
MD .\data
Pushd .\data
$Folder = @('RS1','RS2','RS3')
Md $Folder
```

Where `md` is an alias for `New-Item` and
`%`,`ForEach` are aliases for `ForEach-Object`

Comment: Thanks, solved by using first variant.
In my case it was `PS C:\data> 1..3 | ForEach {MD "rs$_"}`

Comment: `pushd` is an alias for `push-location` and puts the current item to the top. Probably you do not need it but I am not sure. Maybe in the last solution a simple `$ar='f1','f2',..` would also work.

Answer (score 2):

You could use foreach in PowerShell to get this done

```
ForEach ($Dir in ("Dir1", "Dir2", "Dir3", "Dir4"))
    {
        New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path [PATH]\$Dir
    }
```

Read more about [ForEach in PowerShell](https://ss64.com/ps/foreach.html)

Comment: While the parentheses enclosing the collection entries ease reading, they are not required. I do like ss64.com but the `Get-Help about_foreach` or [docs.microsoft.com](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_foreach?view=powershell-5.1) are more detailed.

Answer (score 2):

i'm a lazy guy, so i tried to find a way to make this easily scalable. you can add a Write-Host to show which directories have been created or export-excel or even Transcript to a log.  this is just a simple script.

```
#new-foldersMultiple.ps1

#Collect usernames for Directory names
$newUsers = Get-Content -Path "\\DFS\newUsers.csv"

#Set the HomeDrive path
$homeDrivePath = "D:\home\Users\"

#loop through each username to create their HomeDrive Directory
foreach ($newUser in $newUsers)
{

New-Item -ItemType directory -Name $newUser -Path $homeDrivePath
start-sleep 2

}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, please don't use screenshot for things you can easily copy-paste as text.

The command in your screenshot is this:

> ```
> mkdir \data\rs1 \data\rs2 \data\rs3
> ```

And this will work just fine in a script too, provided you are on the correct drive, in this example `C:`.

The command `mkdir /data/rs1 /data/rs2 /data/rs3` is not the same thing, because as you can see, as the path parameters use `/` as path separator, which will not work in Windows.

Putting double-quotes around the list of paths doesn't help either.
That way the double-quoted expression is treated as one single path,
rather than 3 paths.

In short, just as `mkdir \data\rs1 \data\rs2 \data\rs3` works in your command example,
it works exactly the same way in a batch script.

Answer (score 1):

I created the following to create a PowerShell script that will create folders and different subfolders underneath those folders based on a CSV file.

```
#Set Location for folder creation

Set-Location "S:\Folder" 

#Import the CSV file
$csvFile = Import-Csv "S:\Folder\FolderNames1.csv"

#Loop through each row in the CSV file
foreach ($row in $csvFile) {

    # Get the folder path
    $Folder = $row.Folder

    # Create the folder
    New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path $Folder

    # If the row contains subfolder names, create each subfolder
    if ($row.Subfolder) {
        foreach ($Subfolder in $row.Subfolder) {
            $subFolderPath = $folder + "\" + $Subfolder
            New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path $SubfolderPath
        }
    }
}
```

The CSV had the following format

```
Folder,Subfolder
Folder 1,Subfolder1
Folder 1,Subfolder2
Folder 1,Subfolder3
Folder 2,Subfolder4
Folder 2,Subfolder5
Folder 2,Subfolder6
```

Answer (score 0):

The following command in powershell will create multiple directories (20) named "dir" in the directory that the command is executed.

```
mkdir $(1..20 | %{"dir$_"})
```

I think this command is the closest to the bash equivalent in Unix and Linux:

```
mkdir dir{1..20}
```

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Before answering an old question having an accepted answer (look for green ✓) as well as other answers ensure your answer adds something new or is otherwise helpful in relation to them. Here is a guide on [answer]. There is also [tour] for the site tour, and [help] for the help center.